# 1440p (WQHD) monitor with an IPS panel

Tags: gaming, monitors

I'm currently looking for a new monitor for gaming and watching movies.

The resolution should be WQHD (2560x1440) or WQXGA (2560x1600) as I fear that with a 4k monitor my  GTX1070 graphics card would hit the limit on newer games to soon.

The size should be between 24" and 27". I don't have enough space on my desk for a bigger or ultra wide screen.

The monitor should have an IPS panel, because I usually lie on my bed when watching movies. So the viewing angles of TN panels would be problematic.

I don't have an specific requirements for the refresh rate. 60Hz will be enough, but more wouldn't hurt either.

The monitor must have at least 2 connectors. One HDMI and one Display Port would be optimal, but an other configuration shouldn't be a problem with adapters.

As I don't do any image or video editing, I have no special requirements for the color space.

G-Sync sound nice, but as I usually don't play many fast paced games, it isn't a requirement.

Also integrated speakers would be a plus, but are not necessary.

My biggest concern:
For basically every monitor I've look at so far, there are lots of reviews (on Amazon) from customers that have problems with backlight bleeding or uneven backlighting.
Are there any ways of reducing the chance to get a monitor with these problems, or monitors that fit my requirements and are known to rarely have these problems?

My price limit is 900 €.
But if there are offers for slightly more, that guarantee not backlight bleeding and no dead pixels that might be ok too.

Previously there was a hardware dealer who offered a zero backlight bleeding and zero dead pixel guarantee for an additional 200 €, but unfortunately that dealer went out of business some time ago, and I haven't found an other one with such an offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might take a look at this: [Dell U2715H 27-Inch Widescreen IPS LED Monitor](https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Monitors/Dell-U2715H-27-Inch-Widescreen-IPS-LED-Monitor/B00P0EQD1Q/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1483467017&sr=8-1&keywords=Dell%20UltraSharp%20U2715H%2027-Inch%20Screen%20LED-Lit%20Monitor) on Amazon.co.uk for  £394.93

Fits your requirements:

- 1440p Resoluiton
- 60Hz Refresh Rate
- 27 inch
- IPS LED
- Multiple Display Inputs: 2x HDMI, 1x Mini Display Port
- Under budget

The average review for this screen on Amazon.co.uk is 4.6/5, which isn't too bad. The average is 4.4/5 on [Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00P0EQD1Q).

One review on the .co.uk site does mention dead pixels however, I wouldn't be too concerned since the majority of reviews expressed satisfaction with the performance/quality of the display.

Comment: I have the Dell U2715H on trivial and it's a really good monitor. No dead pixels and no problems with backlight bleeding. I just wish that the monitors coating was more glossy. You can see grains on a white surface